# How to spoof "open" command

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, command-line

Basically, an app I am using executes something such as `open -a "App One"`, but I'd like it to open `App Two` instead

Trying to do something such as intercept the command, in order to execute `open -a "App Two"`

Comment: It might help if you could share the actual names of the application involved. Also, are you sure it invokes `/usr/bin/open` or could it use another way to open "App One"?

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to hot patch the app so it opens what you please. Depending on if the app is interpreted or compiled you may run into gatekeeper and code signing / notarization traps.

Next hard is to modify the open command to special case this. You will run into code signing issues there on most recent macOS so patching the app to call a second version of that tool, might be slightly easier or harder based on your skill level,to compile a command line binary.

Messing with the launch services database is an option, but you likely will get caught spoofing that.

Cracking macOS launch daemon itself would be the crown jewel spoof and might get you bug bounty money from Apple if your exploit qualifies under the terms of that program.

- https://developer.apple.com/security-bounty/

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I ended up making a new compiled binary, which just ‘redirects’ the call to the original binary (now called open-real)

Comment: I didn’t even think that you made the app. Brilliant solution @iCraze

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is simply to change the `PATH` environment variable for this particular app, so that when it searches for the `open` command, it will look first in a folder, where you place an alternative `open` command.

For example start the program from the Terminal like this - notice that the change to `PATH` happens at the front, so that your folder is searched before others:

```
PATH=~/myopen:$PATH /Applications/ThisApp.app/Contents/MacOS/ThisApp
```

If you prefer not using the Terminal here, you could use Automator or similar to create an icon you can double-click that simply runs that command.

Now in the `~/myopen` folder you place a substitute for the real `open` command. Create a text file named simply `open` (no extension) containing for example:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

if [[ "$@" == "-a App1" ]]; then
  /usr/bin/open -a App2
else
  /usr/bin/open "$@"
fi
```

Finally make the new open command executable by running this command:

```
chmod a+x ~/myopen/open
```

Note that the above is just inspiration - you need to actually substitute your own application names in, etc.

Comment: Great idea, will definitely switch to using this approach sometime tomorrow. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: This is good advice but it won't work if the app runs `/usr/bin/open` with the full path.

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work then - but the question did not specify that the full path is used... if it does, there's luckily other ways of getting the desired behavior.